# Why aren't lots of people using OpenID?

Tags: openid

Can someone please tell me why lots of websites don't use OpenID?
Is there a disadvantage to using OpenID? Or is there something about the setup that website owners don't like?

Comment: my 2 cents: I wasn't aware of OpenID until I created an account on StackOverflow.com 2 months ago.

Comment: I'd say it's a combination of "we've always had this login/signup script, so why change now" and "nobody else uses OpenID anyway"

Comment: @Piskvor do you know how the data even works? so if someone signs in using openid, do i get to have that information on my website like last user signin and stuff like that?

maybe that is why people don't use it? whats ur take on that?

Comment: It's a relatively new concept and to further it's use on a large scale platform (the web) takes time, especially because the concept of registering/login hasn't changed for many years.

Comment: @grant tailor: Well, see StackOverflow - it seems to be using the OpenID to 1) authenticate an user (so SO doesn't have to bother with your password and you don't have to create another username/password combo) and 2) pull user data as allowed by the user (name etc., so you don't have to fill in yet another user profile); from there, I assume SO maps this to a SO user account. The main difference for the site (SO in this case) is that you don't have to store the user's password at all; the rest of user handling is very similar to normal.

Comment: There's a two-year-old post on the SO blog, apparently there's been zero progress in the mutual OpenID compatibility between providers: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/stack-overflow-openid-case-study/

Comment: @Piskvor what if i have a branded openID for my network of websites and only allow login with single username and password within the network of websites?

does that work? just like google...like the same signup username and password for all google products?

Comment: @grant tailor: Well, at that point I'm not sure whether it's really OpenID anymore; but if I was making a network of sites, I'd allow OpenID as a login option, definitely (OID is not huge, but the usage share is not dropping).

Comment: @Piskvor what do you think about myopenid? 
what i want to do is kind of have openid within my network of websites only. So if someone is a user on one, the user can sign in with the other with same login info. got it?

so it's just going to be within my network only. is that possible? is that what myopenid is doing already?

Comment: @grant tailor: I don't know this implementation so intimately; maybe ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 11):

Most people don't even know that they have an OpenID account and don't know what to do when they are asked to enter their OpenID. They get even more confused if you redirect them to a different site to login. It's a little worrying for people when they don't understand where their password is being sent. They may mistake it for a phishing attack and leave the site, or they may just decide that it's too complicated and give up without even trying.

If you present people with a standard "Register for an account" form with username and password then the majority of people will have seen it before and be familiar with the process.

Comment: so why do you think stackoverflow allows it?

Comment: @grant tailor: this site, by definition, is targetted at an audience that's (on average) more tech-savvy than Aunt Tillie, so there's a much better chance that the users here won't be scared away by the "O" word.

Answer (score 5):

Because most sites only accept their own OpenIDs ... while advertising the wondrous benefits of using their OpenIDs on every other site.

Comment: @grant tailor: For example, Launchpad.net says "you can login with OpenID", but when you try, they say "...oh, but you must create a Launchpad OpenID, we don't accept anyone else's; but hey, you can login on other sites with the Launchpad OpenID!" Well, guess what: most of those other sites do the same thing ("we accept OpenID...but just our OpenID, don't even try any other"); thus OpenID is perverted to be just another single-site login.

Comment: do you think stackoverflow benefits well from it?
or you think they should not use it?

Comment: @grant tailor: IMHO SO implemented this the Right Way; I like it and it's much better than having to have a separate login.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear lots of people ARE using open ID.

> As of December 2009[update], there are
>   over 1 billion OpenID enabled accounts
>   on the Internet (see below) and
>   approximately 9 million sites have
>   integrated OpenID consumer support.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

It's a relatively new concept and to further it's use on a large scale platform (the web) takes time, especially because the concept of registering/login hasn't changed for many years and the audience is currently comfortable and well educated on the old method.

Its benefits over traditional login are huge.  For example, how many of us use the same password on every site?  It only takes one bad site to collect usernames and passwords and say, try them out on banking sites to see if they can login.

Comment: @Tom 

Ok this exactly what i want to do.
I have a network of 6 websites, forums and blogs and share the same brand. I want to know if i should use openid or not.

Is openID good for a forum?
Also i think i will allow signup with my own signup form on my websites but i will only allow login with openID as an alternative to login with my website.

Is this setup fine?
Whats your advice?

Comment: No one can tell you the correct answer, it's going to come down to a balance of security benefits and how likely you beleive your audience is to adopt this new technology.  For example, Stackoverflow probably doesn't benefit from OpenID, but it's users do. Stackoverflow is the perfect platform to adopt new technology as it has a computer literate and computer educated audience.  Also I would highly recommend NOT installing core features such as this until you fully understand them.  I recommend going to the openID website and starting there.

Comment: There are almost 182 million websites in the world and 9 million sites are using openids , a mere 4.95% .. How many of those are having huge general audience?

Comment: Does that one billion include all Gmail, etc., accounts, most of which never use their OpenID?

Comment: I guess we have reinforced the point that is is hard to measure the internet

Answer (score 2):

Managing user accounts is deeply ingrained in the process of any web application. It is obvious that you will need it to manage *your* users. Managing *other people's* accounts is not so obvious, and you would probably not even think of it unless you have heard of OpenID before.

Except if you have an understanding for the needs of your users (*not yet another user account*) there is no strong motivation to use OpenID - from the business perspective of the operator.

On the other hand, many users are so used to manage a gazillion of user accounts (*anyone here not using a password manager or -shudder- default passwords?*) that they think this is the way it has to be.

Comment: but i see lots of websites using facebook connect but not openid, and facebook connect is included in openid already

so why people use facebook connect and not openid?

Comment: This is what i told.. Facebook connect is a openid and u know that because its popular but other simply don't

Comment: Facebook connect provides an immediate benefit to the company (publicity on facebook when sharing content). OpenID itself does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't entirely technical IMO:

OpenID is a distributed concept, with no central authority (yeah yeah, OpenID Foundation, where else did you see that besides the Wikipedia page on OpenID?), and no *major* marketing effort.

Contrast with Facebook Connect - a technology with a similar purpose; it does introduce dependency on one site, but as there is a concerted marketing push for it, it seems to get more visible results. (only having to integrate with exactly *one* provider also helps)

This is called *[the better mousetrap fallacy](http://www.klebanoff.com/mousetrap.html)*: just because the product may be technically superior, it doesn't in any way guarantee that it won't flop. OpenID is, IMO, moderately successful, but it's not the smash hit as which it was presented (few things ever become a smash hit).

Comment: Ok this exactly what i want to do. I have a network of 6 websites, forums and blogs and share the same brand. I want to know if i should use openid or not. Is openID good for a forum? Also i think i will allow signup with my own signup form on my websites but i will only allow login with openID as an alternative to login with my website. Is this setup fine? Whats your advice?

Comment: IMO, yes. It seems to be working well for StackExchange sites (except for some technical quirks with Google OpenID). Also, I've seen sites that have three-way login options: OpenID or FB connect or their own registration (for users that can't/won't use the other two). Works fine (but can't disclose the usage percentages on OID/FB/reg, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

It should be available in more sites to catch up the trend in users to create their own openid..

But the developers are not using openid because they cant decide on which of the popular openid providers they can use..

Even though they decided to keep some popular providers,  api's which can work well along all openid providers (google, yahoo, facebook, myopenid etc..)is not there...

Unless the developers use the openid for their services or sites, it cant be popular...

So the people who created the concept of openid should not stop by just providing concepts and logo but they should provide multiple api for all developement platforms..

Comment: ""Unless the developers use the openid for their services or sites, it cant be popular...

what do you mean by this?

Comment: Openid concept is new to general internet community.. So when the popular services give the alternate option to login using openids, users will start looking at what is meant by openid. then they will get used to the terms.. Its an excellent concept.. Google and yahoo are using the openid concept for all their products (but limiting to their openids only) but people dont know that are using it and its called as openid :(

Comment: so if i have like a network of websites, lets say i have 6 websites of same network. Do you advice that i use openid, so users don't have to signup for every single websites?

what do you advice i use?

Comment: My advice is that you can use openid along with the normal login.. When users try to login using openid just explain about that..

Comment: @grant tailor: Right, that's the way to do it if you fear users will require site-local signup. (Note the option to sign in using FB)